# How can I check variable in a particular range with PHP

Tags: php

I have to make a php code to check `var x` from 50 to 1000 with a range step of 25 here I will explain it with this algorithm:

```
var x

if x <= 62
{
  then x is rounded to 50
}
if x >=63 and x <= 87 {
  x is rounded to 75
}
if x >= 88 and x <= 112 
{
x is rouned to 100
}
```

etc... until we get to 1000.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: _“What is the best way to do that?”_ - that is rather not a question you should be asking here to begin with. At least show your own attempt first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
$input = 113;
$result = round($input/25);
$result = $result * 25;
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you, and what about the ranges ? how can i check the ranges from 50 -75 ... 975 to 1000 ?

Comment: @MohamedMasmoudi If the result is 75, what is your expected range?

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 25, round the answer, and multiply by 25?

```
62 / 25 = 2.48  round(2.48) = 2   2*25 = 50
63 / 25 = 2.52  round(2.52) = 3   3*25 = 75
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you, and what about the ranges ? how can i check the ranges from 50 -75 ... 975 to 1000 ? or i will not them ?

Comment: The calculation works for whatever value of `$x` you put into it. My figures were just examples. See the code that @mitkosoft put in their answer. It's just basic mathematics, really.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define a loop for desired range (or make it as a function with the range as input parameters):

```
<?php
    $step = 25;
    for($i=50; $i<=1000; $i++) {
        $temp = round($i / $step) * $step;
        echo $i.' is rounded to '.$temp.'<br>';
    }
?>
```